# Passing strings from R to C++

Tags: c++, r

I am trying to use some C++ functions in R. I have placed all my C++ functions in a DLL.
My R code is

```
#load the c++ DLL
dyn.load("PathToDLL\\MyCPlusPlus.dll")    
#call the C++ function from R
a <- .C("MyFunc",as.character("Hello world"))
```

my C++ DLL function is

```
char ** _stdcall MyFunc(char ** strInput)
{
 //display the string received from R
 MessageBox(NULL, LPCWSTR(*strInput), L"C++ program", NULL);
 return strInput;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the strings that I pass from R to C++ are mangled when displayed in the message box. Has anyone had experience with passing strings to C++ from R and if so, can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Edit: I have also tried using char * instead of char** as shown below but have had no luck

```
char * _stdcall MyFunc(char * strInput)
    {
     //display the string received from R
     MessageBox(NULL, LPCWSTR(strInput), L"C++ program", NULL);
     return strInput;
    }
```

Comment: why you are using ** instead of just * ? ( Just guessing I'm not an R expert )

Comment: I tried using * initially but had no luck and then found this link http://www.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~yizwang/software/maxLinear/AlanRPackageTutorial.pdf which says that I should use char** (page 13)

Comment: Just read a little bit more - on the same page there is a example on how to access the strings you got.

Comment: Have you looked at `Rcpp`?  It may make your life easier.

Comment: C.Stoll - I did see the example on how to access the strings that I got using strInput[0] but had no luck. Ari, Rcpp sounds interesting but I would think that my problem has a very simple solution such as wrong string format as pointed out by PermanentGuest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your string in the DLL is wide character (16 bites) and the string passed is simple ASCII one. Try displaying the string as ASCII character.

Comment: You were right. The string format was wide which is why I was having trouble. Thanks to all who took the time to help me out!